# how to make a slanting arrow shaped button

Tags: css

I want to create arrow shaped buttons which are slanting i.e pointing to diagonally upward or downward direction using html and css. To make you understand better , I would request you to refer to the arrow 'Shapes' of MS paint application. The buttons will be atleast 5-6 times bigger than those shapes and diagonally pointing to up or down.

Any sample code help will be great !

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a charity. Try something and ask for help when you're stuck.

Comment: Make it the usual way and then `transform : rotate` Easy really.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this quick example I knocked up [jsFdiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7omLuek/)

```
.up {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.down {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #f00;
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px;
}
.arrow::after {
    content:' ';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #f00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: -10px;
}
```

NOTE: I've only tested this in Chrome 38.

Comment: hi, It is very near to what I am looking for. Only thing is the color of the buttons should be white/grey instead of red. And the width of the buttons should be little wider so that we can write/show a text inside the button indicating what action it is meant for.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to make one of slanting buttons as arrow shaped back button. so made another class as '.left' and changed rotate angle to -180 deg and this worked. But the text inside that also got inverted , how can I fix that. Also how can I bring a sunken feeling when the button is pressed ?